# Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed. error when convert html page to pdf vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a code like that for convert html page in pdf, that code work for small elements like image, table and some text. When i test this code work for a small table with text but when i create my table dynamically in asp table, i generate a big table, about 2 pages, i want to create a pdf with that page but doesn't work because display error from title. My code is like:

```
Protected Sub btnPDF_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserDetails.pdf")
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        Me.Page.RenderControl(hw)
        Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 100.0F, 0.0F)
        Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
        pdfDoc.Open()
        htmlparser.Parse(sr)
        pdfDoc.Close()
        Response.Write(pdfDoc)
        Response.[End]()


    End Sub
```

My error display at line:

> htmlparser.Parse(sr)

thanks a lot, if you know another method to generate pdf with page web for me is perfect

Answer (score 0):

May be save the web page as a html document and then convert it to pdf

Saving web page

```
    Dim myWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    myWebClient.DownloadFile("http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/default.aspx",  "C:\msdn.html")
```

Then convert the saved file to PDF

Comment: But how convert to pdf? Like what i try above?

Comment: You would need to use some third party dlls i guess. I found this have [look/watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYqEXV6JN5c)